# Prove by contradiction that $|f(x)| < \infty$ almost everywhere for $f \in L^p$ ($p \ge 1)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, lp-spaces

Let $f \in L^p$, where $p \ge 1$,  then $|f(x)| < \infty$ almost everywhere.

Does anyone know how to prove this by contradition?

Comment: If it is infinite in a set of positive measure, the integral is infinite. Try separating the integral in two disjoint subsets, one where the function is finite and another where it is infinite.

Comment: FYI: one refers to it as a "proof by contradiction" not a "contradictory proof".

Comment: @GregoryGrant could you explain the difference of the two?

Comment: @math101  It's just a matter of common and agreed upon terminology.  Nobody uses the term "contradictory proof" because it sounds like you're saying the proof itself is contradictory.  Something that's contradictory is not valid.  So if the proof itself is contradictory then it wouldn't be a valid proof.  On the other hand a proof by contradiction is a valid proof that shows something is true simply by showing the converse is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*A direct proof, from which a proof by contradiction can be derive if necessary.*

Let $A_n=\{x \in \mathbb R \ : \ \vert f(x) \vert^p \ge n\}$ for $n$ integer and $b = \int \vert f(x) \vert^p dx$.

We have $$0 \le n \mu(A_n) \le b \tag{1}$$ where $\mu$ is the measure. Hence $\mu(A_n) \le \frac{b}{n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

$$C=\{x \in \mathbb R \ : \ \vert f(x) \vert = +\infty\} = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n. \tag{2}$$ Finally $\mu(C)=0$.

*Now deriving a proof by contradiction from above.*

$(A_n)$ is a decreasing sequence (for the inclusion order) of sets. If $\mu(C) > 0$, the equality $(2)$ implies that it exists $\delta > 0$ such that $\mu(A_n) \ge \delta$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. Consequently $n \mu(A_n) \ge n \delta$ tends to $+\infty$ in contradiction with the inequality $(1)$.

Comment: @math101 I added some details at the end of my answer.